# Group by two columns and get sum?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-manipulation, python-applymap

```
x1 = [{'id1': 'Africa', 'id2': 'Europe', 'v': 1}, 
      {'id1': 'Europe', 'id2': 'North America', 'v': 5},
      {'id1': 'North America', 'id2': 'Asia', 'v': 2,}, 
      {'id1': 'North America', 'id2': 'Asia', 'v': 3}]

df = pd.DataFrame(x1)
```

How would I group by continents and get the total sum based on column 'v'?

For example, I would expect to get sum of values for each continent as follow:

```
Africa: 1 (1)
Europe: 6 (1 + 5)
North America: 10 (5 + 2 + 3)
Europe: 6 (1 + 5)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and aggregate `sum`:

```
s = df.melt('v').groupby('value')['v'].sum()
print (s)
value
Africa            1
Asia              5
Europe            6
North America    10
Name: v, dtype: int64
```

For `DataFrame`:

```
df = df.melt('v', value_name='a').groupby('a', as_index=False)['v'].sum()
print (df)
               a   v
0         Africa   1
1           Asia   5
2         Europe   6
3  North America  10
```

Answer (score 1):

Group by each column and then add the results:

```
df.groupby('id1').sum().add(df.groupby('id2').sum(), fill_value=0).astype(int)
#                v
#Africa          1
#Asia            5
#Europe          6
#North America  10
```